# How to securely store/serve files on a webserver via PHP that are only accessible via a secure login area?

Tags: php, http-headers, data-storage

I am currently creating a PHP website which allows administrators to upload a variety of documents (pdf,doc,docx,xls) which can then be downloaded at a later date. These can only be accessed by administrators after they have logged in. Up until this point to do this I have been storing files above the web root and then using PHP to access and serve the file via a PHP script hence preventing direct access to the files. This does work but never seems like an ideal way to do it as it's reliant on setting the correct headers via PHP for the file download which does not always give the correct results on all browsers. I can't really see any other way of doing it that would also stop the files being publically accessible if they knew where they were located.

What process would you usually use to store and serve files on a web server that should not be publically accessible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample PHP:

```
<?php
    if (TRUE === $_SESSION['logged_in']) {

    }

    $file = '/full/path/to/useruploads/secret.pdf';

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
?>
```

Comment: Isn't this what the OP is already doing?  He seemed to be looking for alternatives.

Comment: @mgkrebbs Yes that was what I was doing already, I was indeed wondering if there were any good alternatives to this but I guess not (I didn't think there were but just wanted to check!) Definitely worth having this on this page for other users looking for how to achieve this though. Thanks

Comment: I'm using this method too, although if the file is big and the user's connection is slow the script times out before download is complete. I'm on a shared server so timeout option in php.ini is non configurable.